# Blogger API: Get number of views and clicks

Tags: php, api, blogger

I have read the [Google Developer Documentation](https://developers.google.com/blogger/docs/3.0/using) but I couldn't find any documentation about how to get the number of clicks and views of a blog post.

Does anyone know if is it possible to get number of views and clicks of a blog post through the Blogger API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Page views per post is not possible with the current blogger api. You can only get total blog pageviews for all time, last 30 days or 7 days. See more here https://developers.google.com/blogger/docs/3.0/reference/pageViews In order to use the api you must first apply for it here https://code.google.com/apis/console/